# GSAP implementing to Vue.js app with webpack

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, gsap, vue-cli

i have a problem with implementing GSAP to my vue.js app which i created with vue-cli and webpack

**What i wanna do?**

1- I tried to create tween beforeComponent mounting, in some function.

**What i tried?**

1- I create my vue app, 
2- I already installed this package, with:

```
npm install greensock --save
```

everything is was okey with installation, then;

3- I imported TweenMax to main.js with this way:

```
import { TweenMax } from 'greensock';
```

4- I created some div into my component for animating with TweenMax.

5- I create some functions into methods of my component which wrapping the Tween,

```
methods: {
           animate: function() {
               TweenMax.to(".rect", 1, {x:100, alpha:0, ease:Sine.easeIn});
               console.log('test');
           }
        },
```

and then i call this function on before mounting component;

```
beforeMount(){
        this.animate()
     }
```

so my tween not working, i'm not getting some error in my console.
I print the console.log("test"); for testing the function is work or not?.
result is function work. I'm getting the test message on console. But tween is no there :) .

Where i make mistake ?

Fully code of my component:

```
<template>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="home">
            <h1>
                HELLO
            </h1>
            <h4>
                How are u doing? 
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="rect">

        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'Home', 
    methods: {
       animate: function() {
           TweenMax.to(".rect", 1, {x:100, alpha:0, ease:Sine.easeIn});
           console.log('test');
       }
    },
     beforeMount(){
        this.animate()
     }
}
</script>
<style lang="scss">
.rect {
    background-color:blue;
    width: 10vw;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
</style>
```

**FIX** . ///////////

***While i wait to answer :) found the solution myself, 
everything is fine with code, just need to call function not on beforeMount(), need to call it on mounted();***